# When I git push all files are update (even not changed), what am I doing wrong?

Tags: git, github

I'm new to git, I know how to push changes when you're single on a project, but right now I'm in situation with three developers on one project.
So I have a project which was downloaded as zip file directly from repository (not cloned), then I made a lot of changes and my colleague made some changes too at the same time and he pushed them.
Now I need to pull his changes, merge them and push, but I have problems in the end, when I push files (successfully), all files update even that I didn't touch and change.

So here is my steps:

```
git init
```

then I manage remote repository:

```
git remote add origin <remote url>
```

and can check it:

```
git remote -v
```

and receive:

```
> origin  <remote url> (fetch)
> origin  <remote url> (push)
```

then I add files and commit changes:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Test"
```

then I'm trying to pull changes from repository:

```
git pull origin master
```

and get a message `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories` and type:

```
git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

Then I have a message `Please move or remove them before you merge`. and I delete them and pull again:

```
git clean -f -d -x
git pull origin master
```

And get some merge conflicts, I fix them manually and again add files and commit:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Merge conflicts Test"
```

Finally I push files:

```
git push origin master
```

And what I see is that all files are updated with two variants(15 minutes ago and 10 minutes ago):
[push result of two commits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGhdY.jpg)

So first one (15min) on first commit and (10min) on second, but why first commit updates every file, does it happens because I didn't clone repository, right? If yes, how can I fix it?

Comment: can you share `git reflog` and `git log --oneline` outputs ?

Comment: @taserface On `git reflog` I receive:
`3db9d5c (HEAD -> master, origin/master) HEAD@{0}: commit (merge): merged
99c97ed HEAD@{1}: commit (initial): test`
and on `git log --oneline`:
`3db9d5c (HEAD -> master, origin/master) merged
99c97ed test
9773d1c UPD:  Updates to the Representatives Block
bbb0744 FIX: CM - Updates for the Events/Tradeshows Block
b1cc45e FIX: the Representatives Block` ... (about 30 lines)

Comment: You should have done what @VonC has suggested but to correct your mistakes, you can cut a branch from master and drop all your commits and rename the branch as master, but first your have to rename the master branch. After renaming the branch you have to push force the changes so that the master branch would come back to the same state as it was before your commit push. Then you have to update worktree.

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate! Now I've got so much to learn and test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A safer approach would be to clone the remote repository, instead of initialize it locally and try to push.

Once cloned, you can import your work (done locally based on the initial zip archive, in another folder, where you did a lot of changes):

```sh
git config --global rebase.autostash true
git config --global pull.rebase true
git clone https://remote/url/reponame
cd reponame
git --work-tree=../otherfolder add .
git commit -m "Import my work"
git pull
# resolve conflict
git push
```

In other words, leave your local repository aside (where you tried a `pull --allow-unrelated-histories`, which is not a good idea).

And do everything from an official clone.